# pseudocode structuring advice and techniques

Tags: pseudocode

I am having some issues with one of my courses, the teacher gives us overly simplified explanations for pseudocode and how to use it and then asks us to make our own pseudocode for his desired parameters which I find a bit too hard for me as of this moment. I am not asking for a full answer or anything, I just want some help in the "key words" and maybe some tips on how to get started and how the pseudocode should flow. I have an algorithm already and I feel like it should help me with the structure. But anyways, here is what I am asked to find (please remember I am not looking to cheat an awnser, I just want help):

"write a pseudocode that inputs 10 positive numbers and gives these results:" 
1. the sum of odd numbers
2. the average
3. the min
4. the max
5. total number of inputs that are even and divisible by 5

Comment: First off: What language? For example, on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode there are different flavors of pseudocode. I mean, you could just do a flowchart, or write out full sentences explaining what each process is. Does he post example pseudocode?

Comment: i guess it is more like "fizzbuzz"

Answer (score 0):

Just a little example for you

```
as long as count < 10 
   if mark < 6 then print "failed" 
   otherwise print "success" 
count++
```

Normally you follow the structure of a well known language ignoring detail and keeping a high level of abstraction.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the example! I will give it a go

Comment: @gengas -- if this answer helped you solve your problem, please click the grey checkmark on the left to accept the answer and close this question out.